# PDF size and minor glitch in export of contour plots in mathematica 12.1.1 versus 12.2

Tags: plotting, bugs, export, pdf-format

**Bug introduced in 12.2, fixed in 13.2.**

---

**Context**

I have noticed both a glitch and a size issue between mathematica 12.1.1 and 12.2 when exporting to PDF a contour plot.

```
 $VersionNumber
```

(* 12.1 *)

```
 tt = 
 ContourPlot[x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Contours -> 5, 
  ContourStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
Export["~/Desktop/test2.pdf", tt] // FileSize
```

(*  36.06kB *)

whereas the same command in Mathematica 12.2

```
$VersionNumber
```

(* 12.2 *)

```
tt = ContourPlot[x y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Contours -> 5, 
   ContourStyle -> None];

Export["~/Desktop/test.pdf", tt] // FileSize
```

(* 102.21kB *)

---

On top of that on both version if one zooms on the edge of the graph in the produced pdf there are some glitches (edges of trianges?) which are number of contours dependent

```
tt = ContourPlot[x y, {x, 0, 1},{y, 0, 1}, 
  Contours -> 50, 
  ContourStyle -> None];
Export["~/Desktop/test.pdf", tt] // FileSize
```

[image]

This seems to occur in both 12.1.1 and 12.2.

Note that the glitch does not appear within Mathematica and can be
seen in  `Illustrator` and `Acrobat` and `Preview`.

**Question 1**

> Could someone please confirm this size problem.

**Question 2**

> Could someone please confirm this glitch problem.

**Question 3**

> Is it possible to force Mathematica 12.2 to produce small files like Mathematica 12.1.1?

Comment: I have v. 12.0 (Win10-64). I cannot reproduce the PDF export issue (there are no artifacts in the PDF file visible at a similar magnification when opened in Acrobat). I do confirm the file size: mine was 37.69kB.

Comment: I see the same glitches on the edges _and along the contours as well_ on Mathematica 12.1 on Linux. File size is 30.532 kB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just test this glitch problem with v. 13.2 (Win11-64) and find it fixed.

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Mmm, on windows 13.2 still produces 34307 byte file.