# "Poor" export quality for SVG image

Tags: plotting, export

I export an image in SVG format using the `Export` command (code below). I find the quality okayish, but not great. I tried playing around with `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`, but without being able to improve things significantly. Are there other parameters for `ParametricPlot` and/or `Export` that can improve the output quality?

```
xmin = -1;
xmax = 1;
ymin = -1.5;
ymax = 1.5;
darkblue = RGBColor["#004699"];
lightblue = RGBColor["#0071b9"];
thick = 0.001;

f[x_, y_] := {Exp[x]*Cos[y], Exp[x]*Sin[y]};

F[x_, y_, t_] := (1 - t)*{x, y} + t*f[x, y];

t = 0.75;

homotopy = Table[ParametricPlot[{F[i, j + s*ymax, t], F[i + s*xmax, j, t]}, {s, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {{If[i == 0, darkblue, If[i == Floor[i], lightblue, Black]], If[i == 0, Thickness[5*thick], If[i == Floor[i], Thickness[3*thick],Thickness[thick/10]]]}, {If[j == 0, darkblue,If[j == Floor[j], lightblue, Black]], If[j == 0,Thickness[5*thick],If[j == Floor[j], Thickness[3*thick], Thickness[thick/10]]]}},PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}, PlotPoints -> 100,MaxRecursion -> 15, Background -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> True,Axes -> False], {i, 2*xmin, 2*xmax, 1}, {j, 5*ymin, 5*ymax, 1}];

Export["~/Desktop/homotopy.svg",Show[homotopy]];
```

Edit: Here is how things look like upon zooming a bit into the picture (using `ImageResolution->600` as proposed below)

[image]

Edit II: A similar issue is described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239458/pdf-size-and-minor-glitch-in-export-of-contour-plots-in-mathematica-12-1-1-versu)

Comment: Export it as a pdf or eps?

Comment: otherwise you can always do `Export["~/Desktop/homotopy.svg", Show[homotopy], 
  ImageResolution -> 600];`

Comment: @chris Thanks, but this doesn't really help, see the edit, neither does exporting to pdf or eps

Comment: I had noticed this: you need to zoom a lot though. You may want to link to this question which I asked pointing out the same pb with contourplot: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/239458/pdf-size-and-minor-glitch-in-export-of-contour-plots-in-mathematica-12-1-1-versu

Comment: @chris, okay, zooming a bit is an understatement :-) I linked to your post.

Comment: Change `stroke-linecap:square` to `stroke-linecap:round` and `stroke-miterlimit:3.25` to something like `stroke-miterlimit:0.25` in the SVG file.  I didn't have time to see if we could make Mma's SVG converter do that for you.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That's excellent! Many thanks indeed! Perhaps you can phrase it as an answer, so that I can accept and upvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This makes it look smooth:

> Change `stroke-linecap:square` to `stroke-linecap:round` and `stroke-miterlimit:3.25` to something like `stroke-miterlimit:0.25` in the SVG file. I didn't have time to see if we could make Mma's SVG converter do that for you.

After some spelunking, I could not find a way to tweak the SVG parameters from within Mathematica.

Here's a way to make the adjustment within Mathematica:

```
Export[
 FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "homotopy.svg"}],
 StringReplace[
  ExportString[Show[homotopy], "SVG"],
  {"stroke-linecap:square" -> "stroke-linecap:round",
   "stroke-miterlimit:3.25" -> "stroke-miterlimit:0.25"}
  ],
 "Text"]
```

Comment: Great answer! Many thanks!